# Change Text Color of GTKButton on Hover

Tags: c++, button, colors, gtk, gtk2

I have this code:

```
GdkColor color;
gdk_color_parse ("black", &color);
GdkColor color2;
gdk_color_parse ("red", &color2);
button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Text");
g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (a), NULL);
gtk_widget_modify_bg ( GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_STATE_PRELIGHT, &color);
gtk_widget_modify_text ( GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_STATE_PRELIGHT, &color2);
gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (outside), button, 0, 1, 0, 1);
gtk_widget_show (button);
```

Although the background changes to black when moused over, the text does not change color. How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't know why this code does not work, I found a workaround:

```
g_signal_connect (button, "enter", G_CALLBACK (changeColor), NULL);
g_signal_connect (button, "leave", G_CALLBACK (revertColor), NULL);
gtk_widget_modify_bg ( GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
gtk_widget_modify_bg ( GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_STATE_PRELIGHT, &color2);

static void changeColor(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {

    GdkColor color;
    color.red = 0x0;
    color.green = 0x0;
    color.blue = 0x0;
    GList *list;
    std::string s = (std::string)"<span color=\"black\">" + (std::string)(gtk_widget_get_name(widget))+"</span>";
    list = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER (widget));
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(list->data), s.c_str());
}

static void revertColor(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {

    GdkColor color;
    color.red = 0x0;
    color.green = 0x0;
    color.blue = 0x0;
    GList *list;
    std::string s = (std::string)"<span color=\"white\">" + (std::string)(gtk_widget_get_name(widget))+"</span>";
    list = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER (widget));
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(list->data), s.c_str());
}
```

These callbacks change the color and font as needed.